# Many levels of __getitem__ in Python

Tags: python, arguments, python-3.4

What to use to get more than one argument from another class? I need something like **getitem**() but with that i can get only 1.

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, ex1, ex2, ex3):
        self.ex1 = ex1
        self.ex2 = ex2
        self.ex3 = ex3
   #just example, this will not work
   def __getitem__(self, ex1, ex2, ex3):
   return self.ex1, self.ex2, self.ex3
```

Comment: If you describe your specific use case you'll get better answers.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `return (self.ex1, self.ex2, self.ex3)` will absolutely work...

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement slicing.

Comment: Yes, i want to implement slicing.

Answer (score 2):

Python combines more than one argument of `[...]` into a tuple:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, ex1, ex2, ex3):
        self.ex1 = ex1
        self.ex2 = ex2
        self.ex3 = ex3

    def __getitem__(self, index):
       ex1, ex2, ex3 = index
       return self.ex1, self.ex2, self.ex3

ex = Example(1,2,3)
print ex[1,2,3]
```

Comment: That always prints `(1, 2, 3)` given any three indices, like `ex[2,1,0]` or `ex[5, 190, 'a']`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this.

`A.__getitem__()` returns and another object with its own `B.__getitem__()` in which turn returns `C.__getitem()__`. Then you can do

```
b = a["1"]
c = b["2"]
```

which is equivalent of saying

```
 c = a["1"]["2"]
```